# Count key value that matches certain value in pyspark dataframe using udf

Tags: python, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe that has a column which value is string json. How can I count the value that match certain value in a list inside the dictionary and report back as a column? And I would like to do it by using Python function and pyspark udf.

For example, below is the dataframe, df:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|col                                                                        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"field":{"list":[{"item":1,"upgrade":false},{"item":2,"upgrade":true}]}}
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"field":{"list":[{"item":1,"upgrade":false},{"item":2,"upgrade":false}]}}
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What I tried to do:

```
def upgrade_false(doc):
    string = str(doc) 
    return string.count('"upgrade":false')

df2= df.withColumn('upgrade_false', (F.udf(lambda j: upgrade_false(json.loads(j)),t.StringType()))('col'))
```

But it's not working. Can someone explain what may be wrong?

The ideal result looks like below:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|col                                                                        | upgrade_false
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|{"field":{"list":[{"item":1,"upgrade":false},{"item":2,"upgrade":true}]}}   | 1
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|{"field":{"list":[{"item":1,"upgrade":false},{"item":2,"upgrade":false}]}}  | 2
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

`json.loads` changes your string to `'upgrade': False` instead of `"upgrade":false`, so you can't get any matches.

```
>>> str(json.loads('{"field":{"list":[{"item":1,"upgrade":false},{"item":2,"upgrade":true}]}}'))
"{'field': {'list': [{'item': 1, 'upgrade': False}, {'item': 2, 'upgrade': True}]}}"
```

Try the udf below instead, which counts the correct string:

```
df2 = df.withColumn(
    'upgrade_false',
    F.udf(lambda j: str(json.loads(j)).count("'upgrade': False"))('col')
)
```

Comment: weirdly I am still getting zero counts

Comment: @kihhfeue could you show the results of `str(json.loads(df.select('col').collect()[0][0]))` ?

Comment: I did that and the spark job ran for a long time and still hasn't finished...

Comment: oh sorry, I shouldn't have used collect. how about replacing `collect()` with `take(1)`?

Comment: @kihhfeue You said you get zero counts. Could you show the rows of the dataframe which show zero counts? please put them by editing the question and not in the comments

Comment: I saw what the issue is. After str(json.loads(df.select('col').take(1)[0][0])), the result is full of u\ and \.

Comment: @kihhfeue can you try with `.count("u'upgrade': False")`?